# StackExchange vs. Stack Exchange

Tags: support, trademark

Which spacing is correct? I've seen both being used. Plus, there isn't really anything saying which is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Stack Exchange** is correct.

> Stack Exchange Inc. is the official name of the company.

(https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

---

A complete extract:

> ### Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name
>
> - Stack Exchange Inc. is the official name of the company.
> - Stack Overflow is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow"
>   (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always
>   written stackoverflow.com (no CamelCase, single word capitalization
>   rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this
>   convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User
>   (superuser.com), etc.
> - A Stack Exchange site is a Q&A website built on the technology of Stack Exchange Inc. The phrase "Stack Exchange" is generally used as
>   an adjective, not a noun. One would say "Propose a Stack Exchange site
>   on Area 51" (correct), not "Propose a Stack Exchange on Area 51"
>   (wrong).
> - The Stack Exchange Network refers to the collection of Stack Exchange sites and services.
> - Area 51 (two words) is the site used to propose new Stack Exchange sites for the Stack Exchange Network.
> - The Stack Exchange API allows users to write applications based on the Stack Exchange engine. The API is always referred to as "Stack
>   Exchange API", even if the application is written for a specific site
>   (i.e. never Stack Overflow API, Server Fault API, etc.).
> - The Stack Exchange Blog is the company blog which talks about everything we're doing on all our sites and what the company itself is
>   doing.